# Finite $k$-set-respecting splitting of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

**Motivation.** My sons participated in a large football tournament recently; everyone wanted to be in a team with everyone else at least once. Tricky!

**Formulation of the question.** For any positive integer $k\in\mathbb{N}$, let  $\ \binom {\mathbb N} k\ $ denote the collection of $k$-element subsets of $\mathbb{N}.\ $ Let ${\cal I}$ be the collection of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ that are both infinite and co-infinite (the complement is infinite).

Fix an integer $k\geq 2$. Is there a finite family $\ {\cal S}\subseteq {\cal I}\ $  such that for every $\ F\in\binom {\mathbb N} k\ $ there is $T\in{\cal S}\ $ with $F\subseteq T$ or $F\subseteq (\mathbb{N}\setminus T)$?   If yes, what is the smallest size such a family ${\cal S}$ can have, in terms of $k$?

---

**Note.** I originally posted this question for $k=2$ and arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, not just infinite/co-infinite ones. [Zach Teitler](https://mathoverflow.net/users/88133/zach-teitler) quickly gave an elegant solution and suggested this generalization. First it seemed $k=2$ was solved, but it turns out $k=2$ is still unresolved.

Comment: I think $S=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}$ works.

Comment: Right @ZachTeitler - sorry. Can it be done with sets that are infinite and co-infinite? Will change the question accordingly

Comment: Size $|S|=2$ is clearly impossible. How about $|S|=3$ like this: let each $S_i$, $i=1,2,3$, be the set of integers congruent to $0$ or $i$ modulo $4$.

Comment: Very nice, @ZachTeitler! Could you post this as a short answer so I can close this question?

Comment: This is a fun question. How far can we generalize, eg, to $k$-team games?

Comment: Thanks @ZachTeitler! And your follow-up question is very interesting! - I was thinking about the "complement" of my problem: can your construction be used to find a finite **pair-splitting** family ${\cal S}\subseteq {\cal I}$, meaning: for all $a\neq b\in\mathbb{N}$ there is $T\in {\cal S}$ such that $T$ contains exactly one of $a,b$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149791/discussion-between-zach-teitler-and-dominic-van-der-zypen).

Comment: For a longer time and these days, the MO-TeX \cal makes posts and comments unreadable to me.

Comment: @WlodAA you suggest using \mathcal instead of \cal, or what is your suggestion?

Comment: @WlodAA: see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5508/did-mathcal-stop-working-properly for a fix.

Comment: Dominic, let experts provide a solution.

Comment: Here are standard $\ A\ B\ C;\ $ then \cal: $\ {\cal A}\ {\cal B}\ {\cal C};\ $ then \mathcal: $\ {\mathcal A}\ {\mathcal B}\ {\mathcal C}\ $ -- the 6 \cal and \mathcal characters shows as squares.

Comment: On a different but still Mac the cal characters are displayed fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $k\ge2$, if we partition $\mathbb N$ into $k+1$ infinite sets $S_0,S_1,\dots,S_k$, then each $S_i$ is coinfinite, and every $k$-element subset of $\mathbb N$ is contained in the complement of some $S_i$.

This is best possible: for $k\ge2$, given $k$ nonempty proper subsets of $\mathbb N$, there is a $k$-element set which meets all of those sets and their complements. The proof is by induction.

For $k=2$, suppose $S_1$ and $S_2$ are nonempty proper subsets of $\mathbb N$. If neither is contained in the other, choose $x_1\in S_1\setminus S_2$ and $x_2\in S_2\setminus S_1$; if one is contained in the other, say $S_1\subseteq S_2$, choose $x_1\in S_1$ and $x_2\in\mathbb N\setminus S_2$. In either case the set $\{x_1,x_2\}$ meets each of the sets $S_1,S_2,\mathbb N\setminus S_1,\mathbb N\setminus S_2$.

For the induction step, let $S_1,\dots,S_k,S_{k+1}$ be nonempty proper subsets of $\mathbb N$, and let $F=\{x_1,\dots,x_k\}$ be a $k$-element set which meets $S_i$ and $\mathbb N\setminus S_i$ for $1\le i\le k$. Choose $x_{k+1}\in\mathbb N$ so that $x_{k+1}\in S_{k+1}\iff x_1\notin S_{k+1}$. Then the set $F\cup\{x_{k+1}\}$ has at most $k+1$ elements and meets $S_i$ and $\mathbb N\setminus S_i$ for $1\le i\le k+1$.

Comment: @SamHopkins I think the "cofinite" bit is a little bug that crept in -- but the elegance of this archetypical bof-solution lies in the following bit (I think): if $F$ has $n$ elements and $S_0,\ldots S_n$ are $n+1$ sets partitioning $\mathbb{N}$, then $F$ cannot intersect **all** of the $S_i$. So suppose it doesn't intersect $S_j$. Then $F\subseteq (\mathbb{N}\setminus S_j)$. (Apologies for this laudatory speech on bof, but I have seen a lot of answers by him, many of them so simple and to the point like a simple and elegant chess move that still most chess players don't find.)